# Low noise amplification - Op Amps vs Transistor based amplifiers

Tags: amplifier, noise, instrumentation

Whats the best amplification strategy to use for something requiring very low noise like an EEG (brain wave detecting)? Efficiency isn't really an issue. Op amps with high CMRR are expensive, and without a high CMRR there will be a lot of noise.. Is buying an expensive instrumentation amplifier (op amp) the way to go? Or would a cheap transistor based ie class A amplifier do just as well?

Comment: What do you mean by expensive? There are In-Amps that are pretty cheap. Or you can make a nice In-Amp from the 4 op-amps on an LM324.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for EEGs there is no real way around FET input instrumentation amplifiers. That is the only strategy to get good CMRR at high gain (in-amps actually get better CMRR performance at higher gain, which is exactly what you need). I don't see how class A has anything to do with it, that is not a specific technology but just a way to describe a broad range of audio application amplifiers. There are class A amplifiers with very high noise and with very low noise.

You will be limited by physical noise in any case, no way around that. So make sure you have as good a signal path going in as possible, shield the amplifier and use coax braided shield wires to the electrodes. EEGs are especially sensitive to electrostatic fields which usually causes irreconcilable issues with mains hum. Therefore you need to digitally filter that out - there is no better filter than a digital one and you need all the precision you can get.

Comment: Medical electronics generally also requires the power source to be galvanically isolated from the sensor that comes in physical contact with the patient. This can be done by the means of an optocoupler.

Answer (score -1):

Typically in these types of applications you will have common mode noise that you need to reject, so you need a differential amplifier.  The exact type of amplifier you need and how much CMRR you need of course depends on the specifics of your application.